# Sharepoint Workflow - Email Settings

Tags: sharepoint, shared-libraries, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am inexperienced with the Sharepoint.
Is it possible in Sharepoint to create a workflow that sends an email out for approval to only the manager of that user that added something to the custom list form.

For example, if A (regular employee) added something to list, B (manager) should get the email for approval. If B added something list, C (director) should get the email for approval and so on. But here is the thing, there are hundreds of A's, B's or C's. Like A1, B1, C1 or A2, B2, C2.

Right now, we can add people who approves, in serial or parallel form, that means either they all get the email at once or one after another. Which means when A7 submits something to the list - B1, B2.......Bn will get the email.
How will it know who is the mananger of A7.

Please let me know if it's achievable or it is out of the bounds of Sharepoint.
Any sought of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible with the the built-in workflow mechanics of SharePoint.

This is the so-called approval workflow. Microsoft has excellent documentation for this workflow and its implementation. See:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc220831190

for more info.

Comment: That is helpful but not exactly what i am looking for, have edited the question to be more specific about the requirements. Thanks for the help.